# Two dimensional associative array in Python

Tags: python, associative-array

I have a set() with terms like 'A' 'B' 'C'. I want a 2-d associative array so that i can perform an operation like `d['A']['B'] += 1` . What is the pythonic way of doing this, I was thinking a dicts of dicts. Is there a better way.

Comment: could you give an example with the result expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use a dict of dicts?  It does what you want (though note that there's no such thing as `++` in Python), after all.

There's nothing stylistically poor or non-Pythonic about using a dict of dicts.

Answer (score 14):

There are two obvious solutions:  One, use defaultdict to nest a dict automatically inside another dict

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> d['a']['b'] = 'abc'
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a': {'b': 'abc'}})
>>>
```

The other is to just use `tuples` for your dict keys:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a','b'] = 'abc'
>>> d
{('a', 'b'): 'abc'}
>>>
```

To get the `+=` behavior, substitute a `defaultdict(int)` for the dicts above:

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(lambda:collections.defaultdict(int))
>>> d['a']['b'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x18d31b8>, {'a': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'b': 1})})
>>> 
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> d['a','b'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('a', 'b'): 1})
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

A dict of dict is one way.

An alternative is to simply use a tuple:

```
d[('A','B')] += 1
```

As pointed out by TokenMacGuy, the parentheses are optional:

```
d['A','B'] += 1
```

Depending on your code, this might simplify things.

Comment: the parentheses aren't needed, python automatically creates tuples out of comma separated item indexes (mostly to support `array`/`numpy`)